# Determining dimensions of an uploaded photo using PHP

Tags: php, image

I was wondering if it is possible to get an uploaded images dimensions using PHP, so that I could set it as a potrait/landscape image, which would help in making thumbnails that don't look awful. Anyone know a way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: getimagesize() http://nz.php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php

Comment: you can use `getimagesize` to get this info.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure:

```
list($width, $height) = getimagesize($image_path);
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure, use [getimagesize()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php) on your uploaded file.

Answer (score 0):

Use: [getimagesize() function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php)